# Solving for the $k$, given the survival function for a newborn as: $S(t) = \frac{\left(121 - t\right)^{1/2}}{k},\; t\in\left(0, 121\right]$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, statistics, mathematical-physics

I'm doing an assignment and I can't seem to solve the following question:

Given the survival function for a newborn as:

$$S(t) = \frac{\left(121 - t\right)^{1/2}}{k},\; t\in\left(0, 121\right].$$

What is the value of $k$?

Comment: What work have you done? Please show your work, we don't solve homework exercises.

Comment: I tried the following: taking the partial derivatives, maximum likelihood estimation but nothing seems to work. Its actually a multiple choice question with the following options:

Comment: (a) k = 121.
(b) k = 11.
(c) k = 10. Cannot be this since the function is >1 with is impossible 
(d) k can be any value in (0, 121]. Cannot be this since the function is >1 with is impossible 
(e) Cannot be determined

Comment: I guess I'm not sure if I have enough information to answer the question?

Comment: You need to [edit] that info about what you tried into your question. And the info that $0\le S(t) \le 1$.